# Asp Mvc Xml Upload

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc

I am uploading an xml and the posting it on my action method.At the top of the received file there is information 
------WebKitFormBoundarytuARn4Bf71AoeFqG
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="samplexmp.xml"
Content-Type: text/xml
because of which I cannot load it on XDocument.This is my code

```
public ActionResult PostXml()
    {
        string xml = "";
        if (Request.InputStream != null)
        {
            StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream);
            string x = stream.ReadToEnd();
            xml = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(x);
            var xmldocument = XDocument.Parse(xml);//Exception (Invalid data at the root)
        }
        return View();
    }
```

This is my view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PostXml", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
   input type="file" name="file" 
        input type="submit" value="Upload" 

}
```

How can I remove that additional data?

Comment: I don't think you want to be reading the whole input stream.   and your action method looks incorrect. Check out http://rachelappel.com/2015/04/02/upload-and-download-files-using-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: Thanks Fran .It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to read the whole stream because it is multipart and is going to have part boundaries written into the whole stream.

the correct way of reading the uploaded file in mvc is

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    try
    {
        if (file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Images"), fileName);
            file.SaveAs(path);
        }
        ViewBag.Message = "Upload successful";
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Upload failed";
        return RedirectToAction("Uploads");
    }
}
```

from this article http://rachelappel.com/2015/04/02/upload-and-download-files-using-asp-net-mvc/